# Display an image from its name (Kotlin)

Tags: android, image, kotlin, parse-platform

i am looking for a way to display an image from the drawable folder by name.
for explanation: I have a Back4App parse database. the images are referenced by their names in a column of type string.
For example: in my database I will have members who are referenced as follows
Last name
First name
Favorite sport (these are pictograms of the sports he practices) images in the drawable folder of my application
Photo (name = JamesPhoto) the photo is in my app's drawable folder
How can I display my image in an image view by indicating its name?
currently I display the photo by its Id. see the code below

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/pictos"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/picto1"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="30dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:src="@drawable/pt_temple"/>
           <Space
               android:layout_width="5dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/picto2"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="30dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:src="@drawable/pt_surf"/>
           <Space
               android:layout_width="5dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/picto3"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="30dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:src="@drawable/pt_tradition"/>
           <Space
               android:layout_width="5dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/picto4"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="30dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:src="@drawable/pt_art"/>
           <Space
               android:layout_width="5dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/picto5"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_width="30dp"
               android:layout_height="30dp"
               android:src="@drawable/pt_kite"/>

       </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pictos"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageLieu"
            android:text="Nom lieu"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/memberPhoto"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="80pt"
            android:layout_height="43pt"
            android:src="@drawable/james"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:lines="4"
        android:text="@string/text_generic"
        android:textColor="#050000" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favorisNoir"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:width="35dp"
            android:height="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favoris_noir" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/like"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/like" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/countLike"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/like"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="100"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the resource using `getIdentifier`. Use the below snippet to get drawable from a resource by name

1. `pic1` is your drawable image name
2. `drawable` is the resource folder
3. `android.demo` is your package name (or your can use `activity.getPackageName()` to get package dynamically)

Kotlin

```
val identifier = resources.getIdentifier("pic1", "drawable", "android.demo")
imageView1.setImageResource(identifier)
```

Java

```
int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier("pic1", "drawable","android.demo");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image.setImageResource(identifier);
```

Or you can use reflections to get resource

```
try {
    Class res = R.drawable.class;
    Field field = res.getField("pic1");
    int drawableId = field.getInt(null);
    image.setImageResource(identifier);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this feedback, new to kotlin I will try to apply it. a question, is it not possible to create a file or other that would allow me to use this possibility in the whole application, because it will be regular. thank you